# Multi-level cascading using multi select dropdown/ list boxes using Infopath

Tags: infopath, multi-select, cascading-dropdown

I have a requirement to provide multi level (2 - level) cascading on an InfoPath form, along with it we need to ensure the choice fields are multi select.

For example, assume we have 3 choice fields - Country, State, City. The requirement is as follows:
We should have  the ability to filter the State field based on the Country that is selected from the Country choice field. Now the filtered list of options in the State field should be multi-selectable and based on the selected option(s)in the State choice field,  we should display the City choice field with the corresponding City value options.

That is , If we choose Country as USA and State options selected are California, Oregon the City choice field should display Los Angeles, Portland, San Francisco for example

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved using  Infopath ?

Comment: create sharepoint lists where will be lookups to the Coutries and States, after this create 3 drop downs in InfoPath where values will be from the lists and fitlered by selected values in other drop downs in InfoPath

Comment: I have those 3 lists and the lookups created. I am able to achieve this with dropdowns where we need to select a single value but in case of multi select dropdowns / list boxes how does one achieve this ?